# My TailwindCSS intellisense and color decorators not working, after following all resources online still cannot fix

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, tailwind-css

I have recently begun working in Tailwind and I was hoping to get my intellisense working for ease of learning and of course, convenience. I have followed all other Stack Overflow instructions and have yet to be able to solve this. I have reinstalled all my plugins, and uninstalled all unnecessary ones. I have gone through my VSCode settings and added the necessary options for intellisense. I will share my config files. Also, please excuse if this isn't written in the correct format as this is my first time using Stack Overflow :)

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {},
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

settings.json

```json
{
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Andromeda Bordered",
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,

  "css.validate": false,
  "liveServer.settings.port": 5501,
  "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "html": "html",
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "css": "css",
    "typescript": "typescript"
  },
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  },
  "tailwindCSS.classAttributes": ["class", "className", "ngClass"],
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "typescript.experimental.tsserver.web.enableProjectWideIntellisense": true
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.16.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.4",
    "next": "13.3.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
    "react-social-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
}
```

I have:

- Reinstalled extensions
- Reinstalled VSCode
- Cleared user settings in VSCode
- Reinstalled Tailwind
- Installed Tailwind directly in Next app
- Installed Tailwind not through Next app
- Added Tailwind intellisense related settings
- Disabled Copilot